# IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] importing data

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I am trying to access to my data on my drive for train the model but i received this error can anyone please gives me a piece of advice

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        import numpy as np
        import tensorflow as tf
        import pandas as pd
        import seaborn as sns
        import pickle
        import random
    with open("/content/drive/MyDrive/traffic_light_images/Train", mode='rb') as training_data:
      train=pickle.load(training_data)
IsADirectoryError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e2ad2e076f9c> in <module>()
----> 1 with open("/content/drive/MyDrive/traffic_light_images/Train", mode='rb') as training_data:
      2   train=pickle.load(training_data)

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/traffic_light_images/Train'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised since you are passing a path to a directory (`/content/drive/MyDrive/traffic_light_images/Train`) instead of a file. Make sure to pass the path to the file instead of the directory.

Comment: can u give me an example please

Comment: because i am bignner at this

Comment: A directory is a folder in which you can place files, such as the Desktop and Documents directories. `pickle`, the module you're using to load those files into memory, require a specific file (and not an entire folder with files). Usually, `pickle` files have the file extension .pickl or .pkl

Comment: so what should i change in the code